# C++ if else statement keeps executing the if and not the code under the else

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have an if else statement but it seems to be executing the code under the if and it should execute the code under the else but i cannot see the reason why my code is below.

If you look at the last if statement where it checks to see if those characters are shown if you notice from 0 - 3 D,W,O,P are not in cells 0 - 3 but it still executes the print statement there can someone tell me why?

will be happy for any help

```
        order.push_back("V"); //V
            order.push_back("I");//F
            order.push_back("F");//I
            order.push_back("N");//O
            order.push_back("D");//O
            order.push_back("W");//O
            order.push_back("O");//O
            order.push_back("P");//O
            order.push_back("Y");//O
            order.push_back("C");//O
            order.push_back("L");//O
            order.push_back("E");//O
            order.push_back("R");//O
            order.push_back("X");//O

                if(order.front() == "V")
                {
                     it = find(order.begin(), order.end(), "I");
                     ++it;
                     std::string o = *it;
                     DCS_LOG_DEBUG("NEXT 0 " << o);
                     DCS_LOG_DEBUG("NEXT " << *it);


                     int i = find(order.begin(), order.end(), "N") - order.begin();
                     int pos = i;

                     DCS_LOG_DEBUG("POS " << pos);

                     for(int i1 = 0; i1 < pos; i1++)
                     {
                         DCS_LOG_DEBUG("IN LINE " << order[i1]);

                         if(order[i1] == "D" || "W" || "O" || "P")
                         {
                             DCS_LOG_DEBUG("It matches one of the above incorrect");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             for(pos; pos < order.size(); pos++)
                             {

                                 DCS_LOG_DEBUG("FOUND AFTER POS INDEX " << order[pos]);
                                 }
                       }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(order[i1] == "D" || "W" || "O" || "P")
```

checks `order[i1] == "D"` for truth. If that is not true it then checks `"W"` for truth. That is always true and so the compiler can probably work out that this test always evaluates to true.

What you really mean is

```
if(order[i1] == "D" || order[i1] == "W" || order[i1] == "O" || order[i1] == "P")
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you like template magic.... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/370195534f4648f6.  Unrelated, I hadn't known until now how hard it is to overload commas.  If you don't wrap the expression in parenthesis, the assignment on the left takes priority and the whole thing breaks.

Answer (score 4):

When you say:

```
if(order[i1] == "D" || "W" || "O" || "P")
```

you probably mean:

```
if(order[i1] == "D" || order[i1] == "W" || order[i1] == "O" || order[i1] == "P")
```

`"W"`, decaying to a non-null pointer converts to `true` when converted to a `bool`.

Comment: So this will not execute that print statement if D ,W ,O and P are not found ?

Comment: @ShamariCampbell: Err too many double negatives, but yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant this:

```
if ( (order[i1] == "D") || 
     (order[i1] == "W") || 
     (order[i1] == "O") || 
     (order[i1] == "P") )
{
    // code...
}
```

Comment: So this will not execute that print statement if D ,W ,O and P are not found ?

Answer (score 3):

this check is broken:

```
if(order[i1] == "D" || "W" || "O" || "P")
```

It is always true. In c++if you want to compare against many values you do like:

```
if(order[i1] == "D" || order[i1] == "W" || order[i1] == "O" || order[i1] == "P")
```

Your check will always be true, because the second check is just "W" which is a char [], value, not 0, which means it is always true.

Comment: So this will not execute that print statement if D ,W ,O and P are not found ?

Comment: Yes it will not (if I have not missed some other error). Execute is not correct though. The if check will execute, the if body's code will not execute.

Comment: hmm strange it seems to print **It matches one of the above incorrect** even when **D, W, O ,P ** are not there...

Comment: Yes it executes the if body after the else body

Comment: Which lines do you pass through?

Comment: Yes it will execute it because you manipulate the `pos` in your else. Thus you increase the limit of the outer for `for(int i1 = 0; i1 < pos; i1++)`. This finally means that you will also include in your considerations the 'D' from your vector. Consider breaking in the else...

Comment: I pass through V,I,F if thats what your asking?

Comment: hmm when i print out the contents for that 'D' is not including i shall try the break...

Comment: Yes i read your comment , what happens is that V I F are passed through ecause when i print them out it is only those characters outputted yeah i will try a break in the else not sure it will work though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8406/discussion-between-shamari-campbell-and-boris-strandjev)